# oh-my-zsh: change background color of current line

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently discovered oh-my-zsh and want to use a custom skin.
I found a good one (crunch) and want to change just one thing. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation about how to write a theme.
I am looking for a way to change the background color only of the line I enter my command into. Kind of like here:

[image]

I even found the [code](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/blinks.zsh-theme) for the picture.

How can I change the background color in this one single line?

Comment: You want to change the background of the second line of the prompt? That would be in [Line 28 of the theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/blinks.zsh-theme#L28). Or do you want to change the background of the first line of the prompt (starting with `blinks...`? Then you can assign to the `bkg` variable, e.g. in [line 25](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/blinks.zsh-theme#L25).

Comment: I don't want to use exactly this theme with other colors, but I just want to use the feature to change the color of the line in which I enter my commands (called the prompt?)

Comment: The prompt is the text that is printed before you enter a command (i.e. **prompts** you to enter something). To change the background color, you need to print a special sequence of characters, an [ANSI escape code](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php). You can start by inserting `"\x1b[48;5;240m` (for bg color 240) at the beginning of the string on the [last line of the crunch theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/crunch.zsh-theme#L43) and then trial and error from there.

Comment: Where ever I put your sequence in the last line, it is only printed to the terminal the way I write it. Surrounding with `%{...%}` doesn't change something, neither.